# Can't catch error status code using .net 6 and angular

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm trying to use Angular and .Net 6 api to catch unauthorized 401 errors. the statuscode of the returned error message is 0.

my HTTP Request:

```js
getLivedata(startDate: Date, endDate: Date,customerId:number): 
  Observable<LiveDataChart[]> {
  let url = 'http://localhost:7287/api/FastCourier/getLiveData';
  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let startDateParam = this.datepipe.transform(startDate, 'yyyy-MMdd')?.toString();
  let endDateParam = this.datepipe.transform(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')?.toString();
  let newUrl = url + "?startDate=" + startDateParam + "&endDate=" + endDateParam 
   +"&customerId=" +customerId;
  return this.http.post<LiveDataChart[]>(newUrl, { headers: httpHeaders });
}
```

```js
// auth.interceptor.ts
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {    
  let token =this.authService.getToken();
  if (token) {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
      }
    });
  }
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.toastr.info("Lütfen Sisteme Giriş Yapınız.");
          this.authService.logout();
        }
      }
      return throwError(err);
    })
  )
};
```

I have an expired token so I can test it.

```js
// cors policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
  options.AddPolicy(name: "LiveAngular", policy => {
    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials(); 
  });
});
```

error detail:

[image]

I think my mistake is in Cors settings. But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I am not sure but is this `https` causing the error?

Comment: I edited it as http but the error is not caused by it

Comment: Your url contain spaces in paths. Try to add `/` in  `getLivedata`

Comment: I copied url but not contain spaces. Also, when I remove the [Authorize] attribute on the backend, it works without error.

Comment: can you link backend code?